# performance penalty of using __LINE__ and __FILE__ in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, performance

this is more of a general question. Is there any performance penalty of using **LINE** and **FILE** in logging related functions? i have been using them exclusively like this:

in c++

```
Logger::debug("Incoming msg from rs232,__LINE__, __FILE__);
```

and my program has been running extremely slow..i just wanted to confirm if removing these will give me any significant performance boost because it is a big task of removing them from all over the places.

Thanks

Comment: the debug logging itself may be what makes your program slow. don't test for performance in debug mode.

Comment: -1 Are you serious? The concept you refer to as *extremely slow* isn't particularly well defined. Use deductive reasoning... If you had removed the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros (they *aren't* functions, by the way) from your debug logging and compared your timings, you would have come up with an answer so much more quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. They are expanded by the pre-processor, and if used in code like this:

```
printf("This is " __FILE__ ".\n");
```

Then the compiler will concatenate the string literals and there will be no performance impact.

If, on the other hand, they're being passed as extra arguments like this:

```
printf("This is %s.\n", __FILE__);
```

Then there might be a performance impact, but only of the same impact as something like this:

```
printf("This is %s.\n", "an answer on Stack Overflow");
```

Comment: Basically you don't have performance problems because of those macros. You might have performance problems because of logging in general, though.

Answer (score 9):

No, not at all. They are macros that expand into some constant.

`__LINE__` expands into the line number as a decimal integer constant and `__FILE__` to a C string constant.